# need something that is same as $_FILES from remote server download with php

Tags: php, image

Ok I have php code that handles the upload of images.
now I have remote post that handles this code:

```
$postheader = http_build_query($postarray);
$url = parse_url($uri);
$host = $url['host'];
$path = $url['path'];

$results = '';
if ($fp = fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 2))
{
    stream_set_timeout($fp, 30);

    $headers = "POST ". $path ." HTTP/1.0\r\n";     
    $headers .= "User-Agent: \r\n";
    $headers .= "Host: ". $host ."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Accept: */*\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($postheader) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
    @fputs($fp, $headers . $postheader);
    while($currentHeader = fgets($fp, 4096))
    {
        if (preg_match("/^\r?\n$/", $currentHeader)) { break; }
    }

    while(!@feof($fp))
    {
        $results .= @fgets($fp, 1024);
    }
    @fclose($fp);
```

The thing is I get the url of the image from that post and it is stored like this:

```
$file = 'http://someurl.ll/image.jpg'
```

And script that handles image with: `$_FILES['image']`

Now if I can say `$_FILES['image'] = $file` it should go ferder, but it doesn't!
I thing that `$_FILES['image']` needs not only url of data but also raw uploaded data

So I want to know what is equal to `$_FILES['image']`, that can can be make of `$file = 'http://someurl.ll/image.jpg'`?

UPDATE:
Hier is what I got as $_FILES['image'] as var_dump

```
array(5) { ["name"]=> string(17) "logo.png" ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpWUqC5c" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(5674) }
```

an I want to make the same but from $file = 'http://someurl.ll/image.jpg'
so the same array and then to say:

```
$_FILES['image'] = that array from http://someurl.ll/image.jpg
```

Because it is remote I would like to handle it as $_FILES['image'], but I cant
so the quick solution is to make that remote image same as $_FILES['image']

Comment: Maybe if you can make it clear what you want to do, you can get quick responses.

Comment: Have you tried `fopen`, as in: `$_FILES['image'] = fopen($file,'r');` ? But indeed, its is not very clear what you want.

Comment: just want to add url of that image like http://pathtoimage.jpg to add to $_FILES['image']

Comment: just updated and cleared the question

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add this function to your source

```
/**
 * Add to $_FILES from external url
 * sample usage: addToFiles('google_favicon', 'http://google.com/favicon.ico');
 * @since 17.12.12 17:23
 * @author mekegi
 * @param string $key
 * @param string $url sample http://some.tld/path/to/file.ext
 */
function addToFiles($key, $url)
{
    $tempName = tempnam('/tmp', 'php_files');
    $originalName = basename(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));

    $imgRawData = file_get_contents($url);
    file_put_contents($tempName, $imgRawData);
    $_FILES[$key] = array(
        'name' => $originalName,
        'type' => mime_content_type($tempName),
        'tmp_name' => $tempName,
        'error' => 0,
        'size' => strlen($imgRawData),
    );
}
```

And use:

```
addToFiles('image', 'http://someurl.ll/image.jpg');
```

Comment: it saves it in /tmp/ but php kohana say Upload::not_empty it is empty

Comment: I was watching to find php script where does it upload? if I var_dump it it say /tmp/ but when I go there there is not... (this is for normal upload with form)

Comment: path of uploading file is $tempName.

Comment: You also have to check if image size is greater than `upload-max-filesize`. If so, the upload will not work.

Comment: on normal php upload var_dump is giving me array(5) { ["name"]=> string(17) "cash.png" ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpUIkqMR" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(5674) } and your script same, and your script puts the file in /tmp/ and the normal form upload it doesn't. hier is yours Array
(
    [name] => cash.png
    [type] => image/png
    [tmp_name] => /tmp/php5aiwy6
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 5674
)

Comment: Thanks this helped me with twitter image upload - works with update_with_media

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Sticks the image in a temp folder so it can be processed and then saved properly. Thanks very much for this!

Comment: @DanteCullari - Followed your link from your post here: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/15588 - Thanks - this solved my exact issue too.