# PHP - **manually** creating the $_FILES superglobal array

Tags: php, file-upload

This is in reference to this question - [need something that is same as $_FILES from remote server download with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913661/need-something-that-is-same-as-files-from-remote-server-download-with-php)

In the above post, what the OP basically wants is to **manually** populate the `$_FILES` superglobal array for file uploads.

In the answer, you will see the use of `tempnam` to create a temporary file and storing the resource in it by using `file_get_contents`, which i think should work in theory (not tested).

Now, my question is doesn't PHP has any checks in order to detect and prevent this behavior or how does `post-max-size` / `upload-max-filesize` `ini` values affect this manually created `$_FILES` array?

Comment: you can populate $_FILES all you want, but note that `is_uploaded_file()` and `move_uploaded_file()` will probably not work, because PHP did not actually **DO** an upload, so the internal-only structures that do the security checks on uploads will not have taken place.

Comment: @MarcB - thanks for your input. That's what i thought, but on seeing the answer in the question that i have linked to, i wanted to clarify if it was a correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` will have no affect whatsoever on the scenario in the question that you linked to because they are making an *outgoing* connection to a remote source to get the data. The two ini settings will only have an affect on `POST` data that is sent to your script (ie *incoming*).

PHP does not do any checks on changes to the `$_FILES` array, you can freely modify the array with no limitations.

Answer (score 1):

$_FILES is just a simple Array created by the webserver. You can do what ever u like with this array. tempnam creates a file, which is under your control. Thats why "post-max-size" and "upload-max-filesize" doenst matter in that case. If u kill the servers space with your own code, thats your problem. post-max-size makes sure, that no other people can create huge network traffic.

Answer (score 0):

For a single file, this is it:

```
$path = '/path/to/my/image.jpg'

$file = [
    'name' => 'image.jpg',
    'type' => 'image/jpeg',
    'tmp_name' => $path,
    'error' => 0,
    'size' => filesize($path),
];
```

Answer (score -4):

You cannot prepopulate the $_FILES array, nor can you put information into the name of a type=file control in HTML.  It's a security issue.  Think about it... If I could put information into the name of the file I wanted to upload, I could take data off your computer without your knowledge or permission.  All that would have to happen is for your browser to visit my web site and "Poof!"

Comment: You can modify the `$_FILES` array

Comment: Ray, you mixed up something.

Comment: // MANUAL REFERENCE PAGES YOU MUST UNDERSTAND TO UPLOAD FILES
// http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php
// http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php
// http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php
// http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

// MANUAL PAGES THAT ARE IMPORTANT IF YOU ARE DEALING WITH LARGE FILES
// http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize
// http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size
// http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time

Comment: Actually, you can modify the $_FILES array.  None of the PHP superglobal arrays are immutable (although they should be). It just won't do anything meaningful for you to modify $_FILES.